# UIBezierPath from Illustrator, Reference Coordinate Question

Tags: javascript, swift, xcode, uibezierpath, adobe-illustrator

I’m trying to capture vector drawings from Adobe Illustrator and convert them to UIBezierPath’s. I’ve created the following javascript to convert a selected path into the necessary Swift code. The javascript functions properly, but the drawing in my Xcode View is upside down and shifted to the right.

In Adobe Illustrator, I’ve set my reference point to center and my ruler to the Artboard center. In Xcode, I’ve included let statements to adjust the horizontal and vertical positions.

Can anyone help with the logic for calculating the adjustment values to center the drawing in a View, and making the image right-side-up?

**Adobe Illustrator vector drawing:**

[image: Adobe Illustrator vector drawing]

**Javascript code:**

```
// create a text file for the data
var file = File.saveDialog('Save a list of the path coordinates in UIBezierPath format.', 'Path values:*.txt');
file.open('w')
//path selection and point variables
var selection = app.activeDocument.selection ;
var item = selection[0]
var points = item.pathPoints;
var length = points.length;
var adjHorzPos = 0;
var adjVertPos = 0;

//select each path and write array to text file
for(i=0; i<length; i++)
    {
        if (i == 0) {
            //get the inital anchor points for starting move to values
            var anchorX = Math.floor(item.pathPoints[i].anchor[0] );
            var anchorY = Math.floor(item.pathPoints[i].anchor[1] );
            //write the let and move to code lines to file
            file.write("let adjHorzPos = " + adjHorzPos + "\nlet adjVertPos = " + adjVertPos + "\n\nlet drawing = UIBezierPath()\ndrawing.move(to: CGPoint(x: "+anchorX+" + adjHorzPos, y: "+anchorY+" + adjVertPos))\n");
        } else {
            //get the path points to make remaining addCurve code
            var ld0 = Math.floor(item.pathPoints[i].leftDirection[0] );
            var ld1 = Math.floor(item.pathPoints[i].leftDirection[1]);
            var a0 = Math.floor(item.pathPoints[i].anchor[0] );
            var a1 = Math.floor(item.pathPoints[i].anchor[1] );
            var rd0 = Math.floor(item.pathPoints[i-1].rightDirection[0] );
            var rd1 = Math.floor(item.pathPoints[i-1].rightDirection[1] );
            var str = "drawing.addCurve(to: CGPoint(x: "+a0+" + adjHorzPos, y: "+a1+" + adjVertPos), controlPoint1: CGPoint(x: "+rd0+" + adjHorzPos, y: "+rd1+" + adjVertPos), controlPoint2: CGPoint(x: "+ld0+" + adjHorzPos, y: "+ld1+" + adjVertPos))\n";
            //write addCurve to the file
            file.write(str);
        }
    } 
file.write("drawing.close()\n");
alert("Done!");
```

**UIBezierPath in Xcode:**

```
let adjHorzPos = 0
let adjVertPos = 0
let drawing = UIBezierPath()
drawing.move(to: CGPoint(x: 305 + adjHorzPos, y: 281 + adjVertPos))
drawing.addCurve(to: CGPoint(x: 344 + adjHorzPos, y: 281 + adjVertPos), controlPoint1: CGPoint(x: 305 + adjHorzPos, y: 281 + adjVertPos), controlPoint2: CGPoint(x: 339 + adjHorzPos, y: 280 + adjVertPos))
drawing.addCurve(to: CGPoint(x: 353 + adjHorzPos, y: 289 + adjVertPos), controlPoint1: CGPoint(x: 348 + adjHorzPos, y: 281 + adjVertPos), controlPoint2: CGPoint(x: 352 + adjHorzPos, y: 286 + adjVertPos))
// …
drawing.addCurve(to: CGPoint(x: 267 + adjHorzPos, y: 281 + adjVertPos), controlPoint1: CGPoint(x: 259 + adjHorzPos, y: 286 + adjVertPos), controlPoint2: CGPoint(x: 263 + adjHorzPos, y: 281 + adjVertPos))
drawing.addCurve(to: CGPoint(x: 305 + adjHorzPos, y: 281 + adjVertPos), controlPoint1: CGPoint(x: 272 + adjHorzPos, y: 280 + adjVertPos), controlPoint2: CGPoint(x: 305 + adjHorzPos, y: 281 + adjVertPos))
drawing.close()
```

**Xcode View drawing:**

[image]

Comment: Hint: By default the iOS coordinate system has the origin in the top left corner with positive y going down.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you rmaddy for the hint. It appears that Illustrator's coordinate system is from the bottom left (opposite iOS). I inverted the Y coordinates in the Javascript and changed the let statement to the View's center. Now it views as expected.

Revised Javascript code:

```
if (i == 0) {
            //get the inital anchor points for starting move to values
            var anchorX = Math.floor(item.pathPoints[i].anchor[0] );
            var anchorY = -Math.floor(item.pathPoints[i].anchor[1] );
            //write the let and move to code lines to file
            file.write("let adjHorzPos = view.frame.width / 2\nlet adjVertPos = view.frame.height / 2\n\nlet drawing = UIBezierPath()\ndrawing.move(to: CGPoint(x: "+anchorX+" + adjHorzPos, y: "+anchorY+" + adjVertPos))\n");
        } else {
            //get the path points to make remaining addCurve code
            var ld0 = Math.floor(item.pathPoints[i].leftDirection[0] );
            var ld1 = -Math.floor(item.pathPoints[i].leftDirection[1]);
            var a0 = Math.floor(item.pathPoints[i].anchor[0] );
            var a1 = -Math.floor(item.pathPoints[i].anchor[1] );
            var rd0 = Math.floor(item.pathPoints[i-1].rightDirection[0] );
            var rd1 = -Math.floor(item.pathPoints[i-1].rightDirection[1] );
            var str = "drawing.addCurve(to: CGPoint(x: "+a0+" + adjHorzPos, y: "+a1+" + adjVertPos), controlPoint1: CGPoint(x: "+rd0+" + adjHorzPos, y: "+rd1+" + adjVertPos), controlPoint2: CGPoint(x: "+ld0+" + adjHorzPos, y: "+ld1+" + adjVertPos))\n";
            //write addCurve to the file
            file.write(str);
        }
```

[image]